# Using VBA to modify Word data

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document.  It contains timestamps which I need to modify.

I'm using VBA to modify the timestamps.  I been able to find the timestamps.  I been able to extract a timestamp and adjust the extracted time in the timestamp.  I have not been able to replace the old timestamp.

Question: What VBA do I need to replace the old timestamp?

shouldn't be hard, but I don't know the vba nor word lingo to do a google search.

I'm working with a Word document.  I'll provide some plain text so to avoid issues with a raw word document. example text: https://pastebin.com/raw/nf4Cc8bu

Here is the code I have.

```
    Sub FindAndReplace()
'
' vba string functions
'    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions
'    https://www.eng.auburn.edu/~tplacek/courses/3600/Strings%20and%20Manipulations.htm
'
    Dim c As Range
    Dim StartWord As String, EndWord As String
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "start of FindAndReplace() at " & Time() & " on " & Date
    Debug.Print "ActiveWindow.Parent (word document name) is " & ActiveWindow.Parent
    Debug.Print

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content
    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
   
    With c.Find
        .Text = "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"    ' Time stamp format
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False '
    End With
     
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim message As String
    ' For how much time do we need to adjust the timestamp so to match the video?
    'Number = InputBox("Enter number of seconds")
    Number = 45
    Debug.Print "Number is " & Number
    Debug.Print
    IntervalType = "s"    '  interval in seconds
    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        Debug.Print "c.Text is " & c.Text
        message = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, c.Text)
        Debug.Print "adjusted time stamp is " & Format(message, "hh:mm:ss")
'--> need to replace existing timestamp here.
        Debug.Print
        ' get next timestamp
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend
    
   Debug.Print "Good bye..."

End Sub
```

Comment: `c.Text = Format(message, "hh:mm:ss")`